# Leftmost border on Excel doc doesn't show in print preview / won't print

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, printing, border

I have had the issue where the leftmost or topmost border on my Excel sheet doesn't show in print preview & also doesn't print for some time, and I'm pretty sick of it!

I've tried fitting columns / rows / all to one page (& then taken that setting off again); I've messed with different custom margins as well as used the preset options; I've gone in and cleared and then re-added borders; re-added borders after closing and reopening the document; I've disabled my Adobe .pdf add-on; I've made gridlines visible / invisible & set them to print / not to print... the list goes on, as I've had this issue for *Y E A R S.* Now and again I'll find myself with a pocket of time or a bucket of irritability and I'll try finding a solution, again - always to no avail. Note: it's *always* the leftmost (most typically) &/or topmost border that goes missing. Nowhere else.

My clunky workaround to get whichever outer border/s to print is to add a row &/or column around what I want printed: on the top and bottom, if the top border isn't showing in print preview nor printing; on the left and right, if it's the left side; both if it's both. I hold the row / column's "place" on the right &/or bottom with a ' mark and select & drag these placeholder rows/columns together to make them as small as possible & identical in size so the doc will print 'centered'; adding this 'space' around the outside of the bordered area allows the borders to print for some reason. Thing is - not only does this feel super stupid, in this day & age, but it takes away (sometimes very valuable) printable space on the paper and, much worse, has to be reformatted frequently if it's a living document, which is a giant and very annoying pain in the butt.

I'm currently working with:

**-** Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2204 Build 16.0.15128.20158) 64-bit
Edition

**-**   Windows 10 Pro
•   Version 21H1
•   Installed on    ‎8/‎26/‎2020
•   OS build    19043.1706
•   Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Reduce a column a small amount and a row a small amount so that everything fits with the print area. That works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion... and yes - but - even if I have it formatted to "fit to page", it won't show in preview nor print.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the print preview does not display a border, but the print will have a border. Have you checked whether the printed table has the top or left border?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input! Yes, I have, indeed, and the top &/or left borders aren't printing. It just seems like there must be a setting or *something*...!